# Lenovo z480 laptop hanged after sometime with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, lenovo-laptop

I've just bought a new laptop and I'm dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. Both work fine but I've noticed that after some time Ubuntu hanged without any error and all keys and mouse movements/clicks stopped working.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Xorg error log:

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    20.580] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Oct 28 11:26:05 2012
[    20.596] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    20.596] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    20.596] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    20.596] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    20.596] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    20.597] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
```

kern error log:

```
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.031854]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.031856] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034229] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034268] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034305] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034340] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034376] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034411] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034447] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034483] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)...

Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.656721] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.661224] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.674172] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.675011] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.675022] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.675026] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.675032] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Oct 28 11:23:21 carbuncle kernel: [   26.675039] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64...


Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   30.425810] [drm:intel_dsm_platform_mux_info] *ERROR* MUX INFO call failed
Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   30.425813] vga_switcheroo: enabled
Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   30.426332] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   30.426334] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   31.027045] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb1) is primary device
Oct 28 11:23:25 carbuncle kernel: [   31.027048] fbcon: Remapping primary device, fb1, to tty 1-63
Oct 28 11:23:26 carbuncle kernel: [   31.199881] fb1: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
...

Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.031818]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.031819] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034198] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034237] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034274] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034310] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *7
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034345] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034382] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034418] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [    1.034454] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)...


Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.498620] [drm:intel_dsm_platform_mux_info] *ERROR* MUX INFO call failed
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.498993] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.498996] vgaarb: transferring owner from PCI:0000:00:02.0 to PCI:0000:01:00.0
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.524928] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.525636] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.525643] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9285 Rev:2 mem=0xffffc900057e0000, irq=18
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.527229] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle
...


Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.700550] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.831907] init: failsafe main process (923) killed by TERM signal
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.888092] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.888096] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.895745] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.895750] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Oct 28 11:26:04 carbuncle kernel: [   18.895752] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11...
```

Latest set of errors after disabled the NVIDIA driver:

```
Dec 26 20:08:42 carbuncle kernel: [  129.894342] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.WADR] (Node ffff880211865e60), AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP (20110623/psparse-536)
Dec 26 20:08:42 carbuncle kernel: [  129.894361] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.BAT1.UPBI] (Node ffff8802118660a0), AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP (20110623/psparse-536)
Dec 26 20:08:42 carbuncle kernel: [  129.894373] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.BAT1._BIF] (Node ffff880211866050), AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP (20110623/psparse-536)
Dec 26 20:08:42 carbuncle kernel: [  129.894389] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_INFINITE_LOOP, Evaluating _BIF (20110623/battery-419)
Dec 26 20:08:42 carbuncle kernel: [  129.894396] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your /var/log/ 's  Specifically kern, xorg, and messages for a start (system if that's separate on Ubuntu too).

Comment: Hi nerdwaller, thanks for the reply. Any specific text that I should look at on these logs? It's because I have several files already for both log and might be too long to post here. Anyway, I've filtered the log files for the word "error" and I've update the above post with them.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to see if the Kernel was to blame (or a kernel level process) or the XServer.  It looks like you have the NVidia card with the Nouveau drivers, which are the OpenSource ones.

I was using those as well with a new NVIDIA 630 in my HTPC, but it was giving me freeze issues (primarily upon sleep resume since I do not have integrated to switch between).  On my laptop, I have the Optimus with integrated intel (similar setup to the high end z480's if you added the card, which it appears you did).

That said, I have two solutions that may work (or at least narrow down the issue).  The Kernel log looks like whatever is happening is during a switch in the VGA states (probably an attempt to go from Intel -> NVidia or vice-versa.

Just try whichever you prefer for a day or so to see if you keep getting the freezes:

> 1) Remove all traces of the nouveau drivers and install the official nvidia ones (should be allowed in Ubuntu I believe, just check the Synaptic Package Manager).  It could be a fault of the switching, which is relatively new to Linux.

OR

> 2) In your Bios, disable the NVIDIA card and only allow integrated when you are in Linux (just for testing).

That could help you narrow it down to if it's the driver or the card (probably the driver).  With it disabled in the Bios, you'll notice a huge jump in battery.  I did on my Lenovo T530 under Arch.  Linux is getting there with graphics switching, but not 100% failsafe at this point.

**Resources:**

1: This person wanted to remove all Nouveau

> [How do I disable the "Nouveau Kernel Driver"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver)

2: This person wanted to install the newest Nvidia official drivers

> [Ubuntu 12.04 Nvidia Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195666/ubuntu-12-04-nvidia-drivers)
>
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: Thanks again nerdwaller, since I don't want to disabled NVIDIA card I'll go with option 1 for now. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Hope it helps, it has been my experience on my t530

Comment: Have gone to option 2 and it doesn't solved the issue. What I noticed was after the update the quality degrades a little. And an hour of programming it suddenly freeze again. It freeze when I'm doing a lot of thing at the same time (coding, surfing, querying in the database, etc). I might try to disable the NVIDIA in bios but I really don't want to do that :-?

Comment: Haha - I thought the same thing.  After I did, I notice no major differences.  But nothing I do in Linux really requires my Optimus.  I can't speak for you, but I hardly noticed a thing!  I found another option, but I am not sure if it's on Ubuntu or not. The project is called "bumblebee".  It's a project dedicated to graphics  switching.

Comment: After doing all your suggestions above, even disabled the NVIDIA card my lenovo laptop still crashed from time to time. I'll append the latest set of errors in my post above. I still the best solution is to switch my development to windows or buy a new laptop :-).